# Unexpected big buffer with QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, buffer

I'm trying to create a buffer on a projected file and the result is a huge blob.
I've read that this can be linked to the CRS used, so I made sure that I'm using a projected CRS (EPSG:32734 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S - Projected). The buffer specifies meters (not degrees like when the CRS is not a projection).
I'm running out of ideas ...

Windows10 64bits, qgis 3.14.16-Pi

[Roads.gpkg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hvW7HGdKR4jw3obAQ7BDg_9FmWTBtmJW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm getting 'Access Denied' on that GPKG.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "I made sure that I'm using a projected CRS". Is this your project CRS? Is this the layers CRS? If so, you made you it to be the layers CRS?

Comment: *how did you make it to be... ffs, too early in the morning.

Comment: it sounds like the projection was `set` to the layer instead of `reprojecting` the layer to the new CRS (If it is the case, your roads would be located in Null Island, in the ocean near Africa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue to access the file, sorry for that.

I also sorted out the problem. It was linked to the projection of the shapefile as @JGH suggested.
My mistake was that I created the shapefile with no projection (EPSG:4326 - WGS 84), then `set` the projection of the layer to EPSG:32734 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S. The buffer created then looked wrong.
When I used `reproject` on the original unprojected layer, then it worked fine.

What still remains obscure to me is why if I `set` the projection and then `reproject` the layer, then the buffer looks wrong. I agree that the layer is not well positioned in the world, but why does it impact on the buffer?

Comment: So you have a point in degrees, let's say around `long -145 lat 45.` 1 degree is roughly 100km, so you get a 2nd point 100km away at `-146; 45`. When you set the projection, you keep these number but tell QGIS it is now in meters. The two points are now just 1 meter away and all the data is located near `0;0` (up to + or - 180 **meters**). You then draw a buffer of 1000 meters. It is really 1 000m, but it covers all the data underneath since they are packed around 0;0. On the other hand `(re)projecting` the data change the coordinates number to keep the points well located (100km away)

Comment: Thank you @JGH. I get it now.